# Error while booting into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot

I have a Manjaro 18.0.4 dual-booted with Ubuntu 16.04 with secure boot disabled and booted in UEFI mode and kernel version 4.15.0-58-generic

When I boot into Ubuntu 16.04, I get the following error:

```
[    2.966795] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e //The number 2.966795 changes everytime
```

Some features of the error:

1. Error doesn't appear for Manjaro
2. Error doesn't appear when Ubuntu booted from the system boot menu
3. Error did not appear before dual-booting with Manjaro
4. In the BIOS setup utility -> Security -> Secure Boot -> Secure Boot Mode -> [Standard], if [Standard] is set to [Custom], I get an additional error as

`MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list`

Ubuntu still runs fine despite the error, so wanted to know if it's a thing to worry about or not and how should I get rid of this?

Comment: I don't see any error message, it's a message, and the changing number is the timestamp (from 0 since booted) and you can safely ignore it.  Your manjaro likely runs a different kernel, or it was compiled with different options (causing the message to be ignored possibly).

Comment: Question edited, it's 0x800000000000000e instead